# using anchor tags inside iframe

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm using a iframe with base url http://test.com/links

```
<iframe src="http://test.com/links?plugins=true"></iframe>
```

and iframe content has a link inside like

```
 <a href="/test"> links </a>
```

If I use anchor tag href in iframe with forward slash(/), the href is generated like

```
<a href="http://test.com/test"> links </a>
```

If I use href without slash, the href generated is

```
<a href="http://test.com/links?plugins=true/test"> links </a>
```

I want a link with base url followed by href content like below

```
<a href="http://test.com/links/test"> links </a>
```

any suggestions using anchor tags inside iframe?

Comment: `IFRAME` tag can't contain any child tag. Anything in it will be interpreted as the `IFRAME` element's text and it's never displayed.

Comment: sorry. I meant the link generated in iframe.corrected my question. please check

Answer (score 0):

In your iframe page, add `<base href="http://test.com/links"/>` in the `<head>` section.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp